# How do I pass data to different threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Suppose If I create 5 threads through `CreateThread()`. I'll need to pass intergers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 to each thread but I also  have to pass a **`this`** pointer. Neither I can pass more than one argument because `CreateThread` function takes only one, nor I can create a member variable in class because that will be shared between the threads. How can do it and how much data can a thread stack have?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/117653/C-MFC-Use-a-Thread-Delegator-for-your-threads

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a struct and pass an object of this struct.

The struct can be this:

```
struct ThreadContext
{
     MyClass *m_this;
     int      m_int;
     //add more members you need to pass more data
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
{
   ThreadContext *ctx = new ThreadContext();
   ctx->m_this = this;
   ctx->m_int = i ;
   CreateThread(...., ThreadProc, ctx, ...);
}
```

Make sure that the object you pass to each thread is different object. That is why I used `new` and created an object for each thread. And then inside the `ThreadFunc`, use `static_cast` as:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
     ThreadContext *ctx = static_cast<ThreadContext*>(lpParameter);
     //use ctx

     //...

     //at the end of the thread, deallocate the memory!
     delete ctx; 
}
```

Or alternatively, you could maintain a `std::vector<ThreadContext>` as member data of `MyClass`.

Comment: You may consider template argument to `ThreadContext` struct and use that instead of `MyClass` that would make it more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a new struct containing a this pointer and an integer, and pass that to the thread, extracting these contents appropriately in the function that the thread runs?

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted, the following answer pretty much says the exact same thing.

Comment: Nawaz's comment seemed to be there immediately after I clicked "Post New Comment", so I think he got there first by a few seconds (and with a much fuller reply!).